# Получение данных с заполненым полем Laravel

Tags: laravel

Хочу сделать вывод постов на страницу сайта у которых заполнено поле.
в контроллере сделал так:

```php
$testimonials = Testimonials::whereNotNull('admin_answer')->get();
```

Но данная конструкция не работает, выводит все посты.

Comment: Так может нет записей, где `admin_answer` — `NULL`?

Comment: У меня создано 20 записей, 10 из них с заполненным полем answer_admin. @RomanGrinyov

Comment: Так остальные 10 с `NULL`?.. Может там пустая строка ...